# How to disable stack trace for release configuration in c#

Tags: stack-trace

I have written specflow tests for HttpWebRequest. When I run them in teamcity server, for every failed assertion I get stack trace. I do not want stack trace to be reported in log. I use release configuartion for running the tests and run vstestconsole as test runner....Thanks for your solution in advance.

`Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<404 Not Found>. Actual:<200 OK>. Status "200 OK" returned by request  does not match with expected status of "404 Not Found"`

````
[15:22:39][Step 3/3] Stack Trace:
[15:22:39][Step 3/3]    at abc.API.xyz.Tests.Steps.GeneralSteps.CheckStatusCode(String statusCode)
[15:22:39][Step 3/3]    at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager , String )
[15:22:39][Step 3/3]    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
[15:22:39][Step 3/3]    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)
[15:22:39][Step 3/3]    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance)
[15:22:39][Step 3/3]    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()```
````